# Apac2 + Cloudflare 502 Error On Static Files

Tags: apache2, node.js

I try to setup my nodejs application on ubuntu 16. I configure apach2 like that;
[image]

I'm getting Error 502:Bad gateway from cloudflare. I did not do any config on cloudflare. What should ı do?
Server is running because I can go this url; https://myapp/
Bu assets not loading
502 Url : `https://myapp/assets/css/style.bundle.css`

Answer (score 0):

I solved with add `/` after ProxyPass like that;
`ProxyPass / http://localhost:8081/`